# How to download Loadrunner with personal Email id?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, microfocus

When I tried to download load runner free trial its asking for business email. how to download the setup?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer support issues, it is not about programming as defined in the [help] pages.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue you need to take up with Microfocus.   Keep in mind the license for the evaluation version is not for production use.

As a commercial tool, the vendor expects that at the end of your trial, if the tool meets your needs that you will have the means to purchase it.  They6 will want to have salespeople follow up.  Having a public email prevents that type of activity in most cases.